# How to use ocamlbuild with OPAM in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, opam

I wrote two libraries ([Bson.ml](https://github.com/MassD/bson) and [Mongo.ml)](https://github.com/MassD/mongo) in ocaml.

I wish to enable it for `opam`.

In [the instruction of `opam`](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/doc/Packaging.html), it says it needs `make build` and `make install`.

I am always using `ocamlbuild` and `ocamlfind` to build and install my library locally.

**How can I produce a `make` file for `opam`?**

Comment: Please give me a reason when someone downvote my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it the way other packages do it. For example the sequence package also uses vanilla `ocamlbuild` and `ocamlfind`. Here's the opam package description for it: https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam-repository/tree/master/packages/sequence.0.3.4 The `opam` file specifically.